# Arithmetic Sequence Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Find a solution for:
$$  \left( x+1  \right)  + \left( x+4  \right)  + \left( x+7  \right)  +...+ \left( x+28  \right)   =  155 $$

I tried with $S_n$ formula, $$S_n = 155 = \frac{n[(x+1)+(3n-2)]}{2}$$
But I suppose it's not right.

I tried also putting numbers in $x$ from $1$ and so on until the correct answer, and I got an answer, but I want to know an easier way when that random number will be higher than a digit.

Comment: In this case, you can determine from the given numbers what $n$ is...!

Comment: There should be $3n-\color{red}{3}$ in there (probably a typo). Also, as Greg said, you can find $n$ from the given data by the formula $$a_n=a+(n-1)d$$

Comment: You've lost $x$ in $x+3n-2$ in your formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum can be written as
$$\sum_{k=0}^9(x+1+3k)$$
Now the sum of consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence is the `average of the first and the last term, times the number of terms`. Namely, in the present case:
$$\frac{(x+1)+(x+28)}2\times 10=(2x+29)\times 5=10x+145,$$
so we obtain $$10x+145=155\iff 10x=10\iff x=1.$$

Comment: In this solution, you already know $n$ which isn't a case in the problem.

Comment: There is a much easier way, that I have found now.                                                                             $$Sn = 155 = \frac{n[(x+1) + (x+28)]}{2}$$                                                                                                                                                                                            $$310 = n(2x+29)$$                                                                                                                        From that it's easy to guess $x$ and $n$ but IDK if that's correct way to solve,even the answer is right.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+1)+(x+4)+(x+7)+(x+10)+(x+13)+(x+16)+(x+19)+(x+22)+(x+25)+(x+28)=155$$
$\implies$ $$10x+145=155$$
$\implies$ $$10x=10$$
$\implies $ $$x=1$$

Comment: Right,I know such kind of ways(+ what I mentioned in my question,randomly putting numbers) but I want some easier way,thanks anyway!

Comment: It is the traditional way btw you can calculate the sum of constants from A.P formula